# Mozilla Thunderbird - Message Filters

Tags: email, filter, message, thunderbird

In Thunderbird you have a field after each rule like:

"Subject" - "Contains" - "**Value Field**"

I tried searching for a documentation of some sorts but failed. What exactly is the Value Field? In the sense that if I type in "P a r t y" will it match the subject "Hello this is a P a r t y" or will it match any subject containing letters "P" , "a" , "r" , "t" and "y"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only "Hello this is a P a r t y". Value field is intended without quotes when you define the filter.